# Run terminal program on multiple input files

Tags: java, python, bash, perl, awk

I have a java program that runs in the terminal that takes a .txt as input and writes a .txt as output. I want to run this program on 100 input files. How can I make a function that takes all my input files and run them automatically?
Here is the java program:

```
java -jar miraligner.jar -freq -sub 1 -trim 3 -add 3 -s hsa -i IsomiR_235G.txt -db ./DB/ -o Miraligner_235G.txt
```

Here is how the input files look like, they only differ in the part between `_` and `.txt`

```
IsomiR_94R.txt
IsomiR_100G.txt
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an alternative, this will get the file names directly with no need to create an intermediate file:

```
for f in IsomiR_*.txt
do
    java -jar miraligner.jar -freq -sub 1 -trim 3 -add 3 -s hsa -i "$f" -db ./DB/ -o "Miraligner${f#IsomiR}" 
done
```

This will work even if the file names were to contain spaces, tabs, or newlines.

Comment: Yeah, this may be easier! Great thinking!

Comment: Sorry, @ShellFish Thanks for the help anyway, I learned the inputs function

Comment: @BioMan `inputs` is not a function, it's `read` that works the magic. -- BTW no need to apologize, this site is about quality, not reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Put them in a file called `inputs` and execute:

```
$ cat inputs | head -n2 
IsomiR_94R.txt
IsomiR_100G.txt
$ while read -r input; do
    [ -f "$input" ] && java -jar miraligner.jar -freq -sub 1 -trim 3 -add 3 -s hsa -i "$input" -db ./DB/ -o "Miralinger_${input#*_}" 
done < inputs
```

This will read the file `inputs` line by line and execute the [java](/questions/tagged/java) script on every input file. Note that they may not contain newlines for this option to work. Files should also be separated by newlines.

Comment: The `-o Miraligner_235G.txt` part should probably depend on `$input`

Comment: should inputs be input?

Comment: DMED7013:miraligner robinm$ while -r read input; do   [ -f "$input" ] && java -jar miraligner.jar -freq -sub 1 -trim 3 -add 3 -s hsa -i "$input" -db ./DB/ -o "Miraligner__${input#*_}" ; done < input 
-bash: input: No such file or directory

Comment: DMED7013:miraligner robinm$ ls
DB  input.txt miraligner.jar post-processing

Comment: No you put the input file names in a file called `inputs`.

Comment: It seems the .txt is created by defaut inputs.txt

Comment: @BioMan Are you on Windows perhaps?

Comment: Is my inputs formated correct? I just copied the filesnames and pasted them in TextEdit. One file name per line

Comment: Try `while read input; do`, without the `-r`. Yes the file seems correct, one file a line.

Comment: Then nothing happens. Should the actuall files that is linked in inputs be in a specific folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82386/discussion-between-shellfish-and-bioman).

Comment: If there is a reason to do the processing in a user-specified order, this is the way to go.  +1.